# Creating first view in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating first view in Vuejs like this:

```
<template>
  <p>Welcome to MyWebsite</p>
  <p>These terms and conditions outline the rules and regulations for the use of MySite Website.</p> <br />
  <span style="text-transform: capitalize;"> MySite</span> is located at:<br />
  <address>Adresss , City<br />State - 00000, USA<br />
  </address>

</template>
```

But I always get

> Welcome to MyWebsite
>
> These terms and conditions outline
>   the rules and regulations for the use of MySite Website.
>
> MySite is located
>   at:
>    Adresss , City
> State - 00000, USA
>
> - Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them
>     instead.

why it recommend me to use v-if? I don't understand what should I do there? Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Component template should contain exactly one root element.**

```
<template>
  <div><!-- ONLY ONE DIRECT CHILD IN THE TEMPLATE --> 
    <p>Welcome to MyWebsite</p>
    <p>These terms and conditions outline the rules and regulations for the use of MySite Website.</p> <br />
    <span style="text-transform: capitalize;"> MySite</span> is located at:<br />
    <address>Adresss , City<br />State - 00000, USA<br /></address>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

For similar reasons to why [React can only render a single root node](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#components-are-just-like-functions) Vue.js requires the first thing in the `<template>` to be the opening of a containing element inside of which the rest of the template will be written. Vue.js is guessing this is what you want, but it's better to make it explicit. Thus, to fix it:

```
<template>
   <div> 
      <p>Welcome to MyWebsite</p>
      <p>These terms and conditions outline the rules and regulations for the use of MySite Website.</p> <br />
      <span style="text-transform: capitalize;"> MySite</span> is located at:<br />
      <address>Adresss , City<br />State - 00000, USA<br />
      </address>
   </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The root element refers to your components root div-like element which is `<template></template>`

So, vue is telling you that below these root components you should **only have one element**: which means,

```
<template>
  <div>
      // put everything here
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you need to encapsulate the content inside a unique block (div, section...).

```
<template>
  <section>
    ....
  </section>
</template>
```